# Turn json to struct

Tags: json, swift

> ```
>  How can I turn this into a struct?
> ```

```
abilities =     (
                {
            ability =             {
                name = "tinted-lens";
                url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/110/";
            };
            "is_hidden" = 1;
            slot = 3;
        },
                {
            ability =             {
                name = "compound-eyes";
                url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/14/";
            };
            "is_hidden" = 0;
            slot = 1;
        }
    );
```

I keep getting this error when I decode:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:

```
struct Pokemon: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let abilities: [Ability]
}


struct Ability: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

> When I remove abilities from Pokemon, everything works.

[image: Image reference]

Comment: When I remove the id and keep only the name it doesn't work either

Comment: Take your JSON output (from the server, not what the debugger prints) and paste it into https://app.quicktype.io. Done.

Comment: Bro you're the best! thanks